# Set Command Prompt on Windows 7 to JDK7 after installed the JDK8

Tags: java, jvm, java-8

Once I installed JDK 8, I am not succeeding to set the Command Prompt to the JDK 7 again, on Windows 7.

I have already set the system environment properties for both `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`, to point to JDK7 and my `JDK7/bin` folder and I also restarted the SO and every time I open a new command prompt and run `java -version` I am always getting the version 8 of Java.

In Java Environment Settings I also have the JDK 7 enabled.

[image: java-runtime-env-settings]

How can I configure my command prompt for the JDK 7 again?

Comment: Are you sure that Java 7 is first in your PATH? i.e. not after c:\windows\system32

Comment: Yes, it is after `%SystemRoot%\system32`. And so?

Comment: MS-DOS should honour the PATH in the order it appears.  If it not, it could be because you have a character out of place. Can you include the relevant paths of the PATH in you question?  BTW your PATH won't say `%SystemRoot%\system32` when you print it.

Comment: I cannot believe it, but why there is a java.exe in the `c:\windows\system32`???? I never got this erroneous behavior before.

Comment: The java.exe in system32 looks for the "default" version based on your registry.  I often delete it, but I am not sure this is safe all the time. It gets reinstalled each time you install on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Peter Lawrey, I changed the order between the JDK folder and the System32 in PATH variable and it works now. Maybe I will delete this java.exe from System32 too. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An answer based on the comments.

`java.exe` is installed into the `%SystemRoot%\system32` directory and this `java` runs the version of Java based on your registry.  If you want to override this version of Java, you need to ensure not only that it is in your `PATH`, but it must appear before your `%SystemRoot%\system32` otherwise only additional commands like `javac` or `jar` use the version you expect. (As these are not in `System32` )

Comment: just delete the `java*.exe` from `system32` having a proper `PATH` and you're done.